# How can you include spatial autocorrelation in a zero-inflated mixed-effects model?

Tags: r, mixed-models, non-linear-regression

I am working on a dataset that has random effects (so I need a mixed-effects model). The response variable is a count (non-negative, integer) which is also zero-inflated (51% zeros). The model that I have arrived at is a zero-inflated generalized linear mixed-effects model (ZIGLMM). Several packages that I have attempted to use to fit such a model include glmmTMB and glmmADMB in R.

My question is: is it possible to account for spatial autocorrelation using such a model and if so, how can it be done? I am unsure if this has been done before since both packages are relatively new..

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this? I'm looking at a similar situation...

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(